# Puppet hiera-eyaml module doesn't interpolate variables in config

Tags: puppet

I'm using hiera-eyaml module, https://github.com/voxpupuli/hiera-eyaml, and want to dynamically set the path for the public and private key. I tried using:

```
options:
  pkcs7_private_key: %{confdir}/keys/private_key.pkcs7.pem
  pkcs7_public_key: %{confdir}/keys/public_key.pkcs7.pem
```

But `%{confdir}` is blank and the resulting path is `/keys/public_key.pkcs7.pem`. Am I doing something wrong or is this not supported?

I know facts can be used in hiera's config, https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.2/hiera_config_yaml_5.html, but can puppet configuration variables be used too?

Comment: Not interpolated would mean it's treated as a literal `%{confdir}`. Sounds like it is interpolating, just to an empty string.

Comment: you're right. i'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%{settings::confdir}` as the interpolation key.

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html#puppet-master-variables

> Several variables are set by the Puppet master. These are most useful 
>   when managing Puppet with Puppet. (For example, managing puppet.conf 
>   with a template.)
>
> These are not available in the $facts hash.
>
> [removed]
>
> `$settings::<name of setting>` (also available to puppet apply) — the value of any of the master’s settings. This is implemented as a special namespace and these variables must be referred to by their qualified names. Note that, other than $environment and $clientnoop, the agent node’s settings are not available in manifests. If you wish to expose them to the master in this version of Puppet, you will have to create a custom fact.